# select items in a multidimensional arrray based on a value in the role inside the array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

i just converted a php array to javascript, how can i select a list of items or item in an array based on the key of the array.
SELECT 'subject_names' WHERE 'class_id' = 'BASIC2' for instance, how can i apply this query on the var js_subject array in my code below

the js_subject array contains

```
js_subject['subject_id'] = {1,2,3}
js_subject['subject_name'] = {maths, english, biology}
js_subject['class_id'] = {1,1,2}
```

with the array above.. i should get an array of {maths, english} when a class_id of '1' is selected.
how can i go about that in javascript?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function trythis ()
{
var js_subject =  <?php  echo $subjects =   json_encode($this->db->get('subject')->result_array());  ?>

}

</script>
```

Comment: sounds like you want an associative array see the section on http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Comment: seems like you are looking for  js object

Answer (score 0):

You should create an array of JS objects:
The base object looks like:

```
{ subject_id: 1, subject_name: 'maths', class_id: 1 }
```

Create an array of these objects:

```
var js_subject = [{ subject_id: 1, subject_name: 'maths', class_id: 1 }, 
                  { subject_id: 2, subject_name: 'english', class_id: 1 }, 
                  { subject_id: 3, subject_name: 'biology', class_id: 2 }]
```

To find those, do a for iteration and ask if class_id matches your element, pushing the subject_name into a resulting array.

```
var subjects = [];
for (var i=0; i<js_subject.length; i++) {
    if(js_subject[i].class_id === 1) {
        subjects.push(js_subject[i].subject_name);
    }
}
```